# detecting ac Phase wire

Tags: microcontroller, ac

I have a 2 wire ac current and i need to distinguish the phase wire from the neutral one (there is no ground) and pass that information to a microcontroller, and whenever swap between the neutral and the phase is being detected,the microcontroller must be aware of that change as well.

I know at least one manual phase wire detection approach(which is to touch the wire with a special screwdriver while touching the holder end of it with a finger and if the light on the screwdriver turns on it means that the wire is the phase), however the need here is an automated one and with a analog or digital feedback.

"How to detect reverse polarity on un-grounded ac outlet" may be more understandable?

Edit : What i am trying to achieve is to detect the source of the current by detecting when the phase and neutral have been swapped.

I have generator A and generator B, When generator A is running, a relay will send the generated current to my house and if gen B is running, the relay will switch to that gen. the problem is that only one pair of wires are arriving to the house and i want to detect the source generator.

I was thinking on the possibility of using the "polarity" data and send that data to the microcontroller, without extra "rewiring".

My thought was to swap the polarity from the generators' side, that means,
if Gen A is sending the phase on the red wire, gen B will send the phase on the black wire.And if i can read this polarity change and send that data to the microcontroller, I will be then able to know the source of the current.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange, jrejory. Your question is very poor because of the lack of details. Explain what you are trying to achieve, define 'hot' and describe the 'manual hot wire detection approach'. We have no idea what you are talking about. Please **edit your question** rather than post missing details in the comments.

Comment: @ThePhoton : I have never heard that technique recommended here in 240V land...

Comment: Could he mean something like the [Fluke 2AC](http://en-us.fluke.com/products/electrical-testers/fluke-2ac-electrical-tester.html)?

Comment: @rdtsc : he could mean that yes ;) , something like that but with a feedback wire instead of the light?

Comment: @ThePhoton : I am trying my best, Please reread now.Thanks.

Comment: @jrejory, are you trying to make a micro-processor based Phase and Neutral Indicator? Why do you need it to work without a ground connection? (The [screwdriver phase tester](http://www.electricaltechnology.org/2013/10/working-and-construction-of-electric-phase-or-line-tester.html) works by getting a tiny current to flow through the finger and body capacitance to ground.)

Comment: @transistor : Thank you for letting me know what to clarify, I re-edited the question, and concerning the ground connection, Where I live they do not use ground...( do not ask me why). Thanks again.

Comment: If there are only one pair of wires running to your house then where is the relay? There is no 'polarity' on AC - it alternates. If there is no earth connection you may have two live wires and no neutral. Please add a schematic to your question so we can understand the setup. Theres a schematic button on the editor toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and safest method would be to monitor the two generators with mains-voltage relays. I've assumed 230 V but you can change to suit your supply.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJnoJp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The relay coil when energised will close its contact. Since the contact is isolated from the coil side it can safely be used to signal to your microcontroller.

- Mount all the components securely in a plastic case (especially since you have no earth).
- Orient the relays so that mains wiring can be kept on one side and DC wiring on the other.
- I've shown a manual select switch to switch between generators. Be careful with this. Ideally the switch should have a centre-off position so that you never switch suddenly from one supply to the other. The reason is that the two supplies may be out of phase and, for example, one supply at maximum positive voltage while the other is at maximum negative voltage. Switching motors or even computer power supplies suddenly from one to the other could cause some damage.

Comment: Required warning: NEVER EVER allow your generated electricity to find its way onto the utility's equipment!!!!  Not by accident, not by failure of your equipment, NEVER!!!  You can electrocute a lineman and be held liable for it.  To satisfy the non-technical authorities that this will never happen, you'll be required to use a manufactured, pre-approved transfer switch for the "SELECT" relay that is likely to be expensive to cover the certification costs.  And you might be forbidden to install it yourself, in favor of a licensed electrician.

Answer (score 0):

use a 10PF capacitor with 100M in series, turn on the
microcontrollers weak pull up you'll see peroodic zeros on the gpio if
the capacitor is connected to phase.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fl6ICN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

this is a rough equivalent of those voltage detecting pens.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work for him. Ground reference seems very vague and I suspect that everything is live so no matter which wire he connects your circuit to he's going to get a reading.